# Couldn't connect to mongo DB server (Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error)

Tags: mongodb

I've tried to connect to Mongo for Freecodecamp Back End Development and APIs course. I tried several methods like checking dbPath and removing .sock file, but it keeps showing. Therefore, I investigated more and tried to change the permission but I still couldn't and Im out of idea now. Please checkout how I tried to solve this issue.

1. Cannot connect to Mongo
   [image: 1. Cannot connect to Mongo]
2. Check mongo status. Found 3584 error
   [image: 2. Check mongo status. Found 3584 error]
3. Check dbPath
   [image: 3. Check dbPath]
4. Remove .sock file
   [image: 4. Remove .sock file]

5.It reappears when I start mongo
[image: reappears when I start mongo]

6. So I checked permission and tried to change it
   [image: check permission]

[image: tried to change permission]

7. tried mongod [image]

Please let me know if there's any other way that I can resolve this issue. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Have a look at the logfile!

Comment: When you run just `mongod` then the config file (i.e. `/etc/mongod.conf`) is not used.